# LetterHead Logo, Title and Slogan Design with iTextSharp, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, itext

[image]

How to achieve the above result with iTextSharp?

1. logo should fit in cell, cell width and height should be fixed.
2. company name should start from left to right, and justified to fill the whole cell with NoWrap. if company name is longer than font size becomes small or space between characters become less.
3. slogan alignment should be in center, left and right padding should be applied. slogan should stay in center. font size doesn't   matter.

Final result will look like below
[image]

***result for the text should work like Viewbox in wpf***

Sorry For bad English.

Please Help. **complete answer would be appreciated**

Thanks.

**My Approaches:**

i have created table with 3 columns

```
PdfPTable HeaderTable = new PdfPTable(3);
float[] widths = new float[] { .35f, 1.5f, 2.5f };
HeaderTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
```

columns 1 contain logo

```
iTextSharp.text.Image myImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(PdfSettingProperties.LogoPath);
PdfPCell logoCell = new PdfPCell(myImage, true);
```

true is for logo to fit in cell

Second Column will have 2 rows. 1st row will be for company name and 2nd row will for slogan.
in 3rd column i will add some other information.

Comment: What have you tried to approach these requirements?

Comment: i have create table with 3 columns. columns 1 is for logo. cloumns 2 will have 2 rows. row 1 will be for company name and row 2 will be for slogan. in columns 3 i will add some other information.

Comment: My approach would be add image at that location then add two paragraphs at required location.

Comment: thanks @BhubanShrestha, complete answer would be appreciated

Comment: why not use [`SetAbsolutePosition`](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/87/itextsharp-working-with-images)?

Comment: You explained your approaches. How did they fail?

Comment: my approaches is working for logo but not for title and slogan. both the company name and slogan will be changed accordingly. they may be lengthy or short.

Comment: I came up with different approach. i will post it in a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem slightly different.
my problem was that Company name should fit in cell with No Wrap and text should be justified. same like Viewbox in Wpf.

Since i'm using wpf, what i did, i design Letter Head in Grid  as below and Convert it into image

```
<Grid x:Name="LetterHeadGrid" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Border
                Width="40"
                Height="40"
                Padding="2"
                BorderThickness="0">
                <Image Source="/Resources/logo.png" />
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <Viewbox
                    Width="100"
                    MinHeight="15"
                    MaxHeight="40"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Stretch="Fill">
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="titleBlock"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoBold}"
                        Text="HCSTP" />
                </Viewbox>

            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

        <Border
            x:Name="border"
            Margin="08,02,0,0"
            Padding="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            BorderThickness="0,.7,0,0">
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.3" Color="Black" />
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <Viewbox
                Width="132"
                MinHeight="10"
                MaxHeight="13"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Stretch="Fill">
                <TextBlock
                    x:Name="slognBlock"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource LatoRegular}"
                    Text="Passion To Design Future"
                    TextAlignment="Center" />
            </Viewbox>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

c#, code behind

```
       UIElement element = LetterHeadGrid as UIElement;

        Size theTargetSize = new Size(260, 72);
        element.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        element.Arrange(new Rect(theTargetSize));
        // to affect the changes in the UI, you must call this method at the end to apply the new changes
        element.UpdateLayout();

        double dpiScale = 600.0 / 96;

        double dpiX = 600.0;
        double dpiY = 600.0;

        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(Convert.ToInt32((theTargetSize.Width) * dpiScale), Convert.ToInt32((theTargetSize.Height) * dpiScale), dpiX, dpiY, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        element.Measure(theTargetSize);
        element.Arrange(new Rect(theTargetSize));
        rtb.Render(element);

        PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
        string filePath = "LetterHead.png";
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
            using (Stream stm = File.Create(filePath))
            {
                png.Save(stm);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (Stream stm = File.Create(filePath))
            {
                png.Save(stm);
            }
        }
```

and add image path the cell

```
iTextSharp.text.Image myImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("LetterHead.png");
        PdfPCell logoCell = new PdfPCell(myImage, true) {Padding = 2f};
        logoCell.Border = 0;
        logoCell.MinimumHeight = 17f;
```

Note: I'm still waiting for best answer